# Adjusting Volume in Android Audiomanager is inaccurate

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

in my Android Application i have a method, which allows me to adjust the volume. This works like it should.

```
public void adjustVolume(int adjustType){
    if(myAudioManager == null) {
        myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }
    if (adjustType == 0){

        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mute audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(adjustType == 1) {
        myAudioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "decrease volume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (adjustType == 2){
        myAudioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "increase volume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (adjustType == 3){
        int maxVolume = myAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
        myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Max volume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Volume is " + myAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM));
}
```

e.g. I can call `adjustVolume(1)` to decrease the volume, and `adjustVolume(2)` to increase the volume. From Volume zero, to max volume it takes **15 steps**

So far, so good.

Now I have another method, where I want to set the volume directly:

```
public void adjustVolumeDirect(int volumeValue) {
    if(myAudioManager == null) {
        myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    //maxVolume is 7
    int maxVolume = myAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);

    float factor = (float)volumeValue / 100;
    int targetVolume = (int) (maxVolume * factor);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"MAX_VOLUME = "+maxVolume+" VOLUMEVALUE = " +volumeValue+ " TARGET VOLUME = " + targetVolume + "factor = " + factor);
    myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,targetVolume , AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

}
```

e.g. 
`adjustVolumeDirect(100)` should set the Volume to max. `adjustVolumeDirect(50)` should set in to 50% and so on.
And this part does not work like I expect it. I can only set the volume in **7 steps!** The method above gives me 15 steps!

Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this?
I want to set the volume in 10-steps:

```
adjustVolumeDirect(10) = 10%
adjustVolumeDirect(20) = 20%
...
adjustVolumeDirect(100) = 100%
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have a different number of steps is probably because two different audio streams are affected - for example the system audio stream, which may have 7 steps and the media audio stream, which might have 15.

The number of steps are different for various android devices and are defined in the system. See also [this issue in the android bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25920).

There are different ways to allow a finer tuning depending on your device. You can probably find some more information [here on the android stackexchange site](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46979/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-volume-levels).

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved the issue with this:

```
mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(audio.STREAM_MUSIC)**/3**
mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(audio.STREAM_MUSIC)**/2**

mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(mAudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)/3, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```